# Substantivierung von zusammengesetzten schwachen Verben

Tags: verb, noun, compound

Beispiel: **fertig machen**, **bereit machen**, **zusammen schreiben**

Wird hier eine Substantivierung ausnahmslos immer zusammen geschrieben?
(**das Fertigmachen**, **das Bereitmachen**, **das Zusammenschreiben**)

Die vom Duden empfohlenen Schreibweisen der Verben sind immer auseinander geschrieben.
Eine Substantivierung fügt sie jedoch zwanghaft wieder zusammen? Oder gibt es eine andere Form?

Das ist jetzt nur eine Ja-/Nein-Frage, aber ich brauche dringend eine Antwort. Danke.

Comment: Mir fällt zur Zeit kein Gegenbeispiel ein. Das soll natürlich nicht heißen, dass es keins gibt...

Comment: Ein Downvote ohne Kommentar und Grund? Herzlichen Dank…

Comment: „Zusammen schreiben“ ist falsch, außer in der Bedeutung ‘gemeinsam schreiben’ (_X und Y haben das Buch zusammen geschrieben_).

Comment: »Das Zusammenschreiben zweier Wörter ist manchmal korrekt« vs. »Das Zusammenschreiben von X und Y ist erfolgreich«… Ihre Aussage hilft leider nicht weiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ich bin zufällig auf die entsprechende (implizite) Regel im Regelwerk [Deutsche Rechtschreibung. Regeln und Wörterverzeichnis](http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/service/reform/) gestoßen:

> **§ 37** Substantive, Adjektive, Verbstämme, Pronomen oder Partikeln können mit Substantiven Zusammensetzungen bilden. Man schreibt sie ebenso wie mehrteilige Substantivierungen zusammen.
>
> […]
>
> (2) Mehrteilige Substantivierungen, zum Beispiel:
>
> *das Holzholen, das Inkrafttreten; der Kehraus, das Stelldichein, das Vergissmeinnicht*

und

> **§ 57** Wörter anderer Wortarten schreibt man groß, wenn sie als Substantive gebraucht werden (= Substantivierungen).
>
> […]
>
> Siehe dazu folgende Beispiele:
>
> *Das Inkrafttreten (a, b, c) des Gesetzes verzögert sich* […]

Answer (score 1):

Ich habe zwar kein definitives Wissen, denke aber, das wird in der Tat so sein.

Die Logik ist dabei die folgende: wie würde denn ein fiktives Gegenbeispiel aussehen? Nehmen wir z.B. "fertig machen" und machen daraus "das Fertig machen". Sieht falsch aus, oder? Wir haben hier kein Substantiv mehr, sondern eine merkwürdige Zusammenstellung aus Substantiv und Verb, allerdings müsste das Verb ja zum Substantiv gehören, das ist schließlich das Ziel der Substantivierung.

Das Beispiel kann man vermutlich repräsentativ für alle anderen Fälle sehen: würde so eine Substantivierung getrennt geschrieben werden, wäre das Verb abgetrennt und somit nicht mehr Teil des Substantivs, was nach Definition Quatsch ist. Daher die Feststellung: muss eigentlich immer zusammengeschrieben werden.

Comment: Logisch argumentiert, denoch ist es nicht so, denn dann was macht man bei phrasenhaften Verbindungen... z.B.  "Vor dem Müllrunterbringen" oder "Beim die Tauben auf dem Dach Beobachten"... das kann man nicht zusammenschreiben. Ich glaube, hier ist keine echte Regel möglich. Ich persönlich tendiere zu "beim die Tauben auf dem Dach beobachten" auch wenn es unlogisch ist.

Comment: @Emanuel das kommt wohl von dem Zusatz den du eingeschoben hast. *"beim Tauben beobachten"* vs *"beim Taubenbeobachten"*

Comment: @Vogel612... wie würdest du das denn schreiben... "Taubenbeobachten" oder getrennt? Ich glaube, keiner könnte "Taubenbeobachten" flüssig vom Blatt vorlesen, und darum geht es ja im Endeffekt irgendwie.

Comment: "Tauben beobachten" ist kein zusammengesetztes schwaches Verb - das geht komplett an dem Thema vorbei. "Taubenbeobachten" gibt es schlichtweg nicht. Es gibt auch nicht "ich will taubenbeobachten". Also hat es eigentlich hiermit nichts zu tun. Besides that: "Ich beobachte Tauben auf dem Dach" oder "beim Beobachten von Tauben" - aber es gibt hier keinen Grund das zusammen zu schreiben. (Satzglieder Praedikat + Objekt)

Comment: @Nikolai: Ja das sieht falsch aus. Es gaebe dann noch die Moeglichkeit "das fertig Machen", aber das sieht auch nicht richtiger aus.