# Verb-derived noun and capitalization

Tags: verb, noun, capitalization

Any verb, which is derived to a noun, is written capitalized, like

> Die Struktur kann **genutzt** werden, um die Aufgabe zu erleichtern

vs.

> Das **Nutzen** der Struktur erleichtert die Aufgabe.

But what if you want to say someting like that using the proverb "zunutze machen"? Does it have to be capitalized, and if so, which word? What is right:

> Durch **zunutze machen** der Struktur kann die Aufgabe erleichtert werden.

or

> Durch **Zunutze machen** der Struktur kann die Aufgabe erleichtert werden.

or

> Durch **zunutze Machen** der Struktur kann die Aufgabe erleichtert werden.

or even something else?

Comment: *zu Nutze machen* is allowed as well, to add to the confusion ;)

Comment: Yes, but I try to avoid spellings which are not recommended by Duden. Maybe they drop the spelling eventually with the next orthography reform :D

Comment: Related (in German): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20475/zum-hieressen-hier-essen-oder-hier-essen, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10394/substantivierung-von-zusammengesetzten-schwachen-verben

Comment: Sowohl Nominalstil als auch Phrasen mit _machen_ werden oft als Zeichen schlechten Stils gedeutet. _Ausnutzen_ would probably be appropriate in this case, otherwise _Zunutzemachen_ or _Sichzunutzemachen_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Es heißt richtig: "*sich* etwas zunutze machen"
2. Ich helfe mir bei solchen Wortbildungen damit, dass ich erst mal einen Artikel zum substantivierten Verb hinzufüge - Dann wird es für mich einfacher.
3. Ich werfe noch eine Schreibung in den Ring, die ich als einzige substantivierte Form glaube, schon einmal gesehen zu haben:

> Durch das sich Zunutzemachen des xyz-Effekts erreicht man....

Allerdings malt mir meine Rechtschreibeprüfung eine schöne rote Wellenlinie drunter. Ich habe mal bei ngrams geschaut, dort finden sich einige Texte aus einigermassen glaubwürdigen (meistens juristischen) Quellen.

Da sich (für mich) **alle** substantivierten Formen dieses Verbs ausgesprochen "schräg" anhören, würde ich allerdings nicht auf die Idee kommen, einen Satz so zu schreiben, sondern versuchen, diese Form komplett zu umgehen, z.B.

> Indem man sich den xyz-Effekt zunutze macht, kann man...

Comment: Im Duden steht nichts davon, dass man es zusammen schreiben dürfte, weshalb ich davon ausgehe, dass auch "Zunutzemachen" falsch ist. Evtl war es aber bei der alten Rechtschreibung erlaubt, was das Vorkommen in den juristischen Texten erklären würde. Und ich finde nicht, dass es sich komisch anhört, wenn man sagt: `Durch zunutze machen des Effekts xyz...`, wie auch immer man es schreiben mag

Comment: @ChristianDreher Nochmal: *sich etwas zunutze machen* ist reflexiv. Ohne "sich" ergibt es keinen rechten Sinn, weil der Nutznießer fehlt. Deswegen hört sich dein Beispielsatz im Kommentar nicht nur komisch an, sondern ist schlicht falsch.

Comment: Ich habe mal kurz nachgeschaut, §37 und §57 des Duden zusammengenommen scheinen mir bezüglich der Zusammenschreibung recht zu geben.

Comment: [Mein™ Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sich+Zunutzemachen%2CSich+Zunutzemachen%2CZunutzemachen%2CSichzunutzemachen&year_start=1873&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3) findet _sich Zunutzemachen_ nicht. Meines Erachtens müsste man konsequenterweise alles zusammen schreiben, also _Sichzunutzemachen_, oder durckoppeln, _Sich-zu-Nutze-machen_ (o.ä.).

Comment: Wikipedia meint zum Sichzunutzemachen: "**Möglich** ist allerdings eine **okkasionelle** Konversion reflexiver Verben, bei der das Wort sich und der Infinitiv zusammengeschrieben werden (das Sichbeklagen)" Warum ich das "Sich" erst dazuziehen und dann im Interesse der Lesbarkeit wieder durch einen Bindestrich abtrennen soll, will mir nicht recht einleuchten. Im Duden habe ich dazu auf die Schnelle nichts gefunden

Comment: @Crissov Meine Fundstellen sind nicht direkt aus ngrams, sondern in der Ergebnisliste >1990 gesucht. Die "nach der Reform" (leider nur wenige  Treffer) haben allerdings tatsächlich das "Sich" mit einbezogen und dann wieder entkoppelt.....

Comment: @tofro Hast du ein Beispiel? Ich kann keine Fundstelle für substantiviertes _Zunutzemachen_ mit Reflexivpronomen _sich_ entdecken – weder zusammen noch auseinander geschrieben.

Comment: Okay, super, vielen Dank für die zahlreichen Antworten. Ich habe da einige Dinge falsch aufgefasst anfangs

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case of *sich etwas zunutze machen* the orthographic rules are not clear. They are clear in cases such as *das Vorgehen, das Zufußgehen* and other more simple verbs.

However, since German greatly adores compound nouns (or nouns derived from multiple fragments) written together as one word, I would also like to suggest *das Sichzunutzemachen* or *das Zunutzemachen*. (I am also unsure whether the reflexive pronoun can be left out; if it is not, put it into the compound noun.)

Crissov and Tofro have mentioned the stylistic problems with such constructions so I won’t go into detail there …